# Google chrome has ghost element on :hover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover

I have this strange "ghost" little black box at the top left corner if I hover some elements.

So when `:hovering` the red box all is good and box changes to orange. But then when mouse moves to the green `.resize-bar` then a blackish box appears at the top left corner. Using Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 on OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Same problem is reproducible in Opera Version 46.0.2597.32 on macOS.

Where is it coming from? Why is it there and how to remove it?

[image]

This is the smallest amount of code needed to reproduce:

```css
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid {
    width: 100px;
}

.grid div[class*='col-'] {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}

.resize-bar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 5px;
    background-color: green;
}

.col-1-4 {
    background-color:red;
}

.col-1-4:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="col-1-4 scrollable">
        <span class="resize-bar"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[And here is a fiddle if anyone has time to play with it](https://jsfiddle.net/ppvha2bp/)

Comment: I'm not getting the same issue. Are there any browser addons that might be interfering? To be clear, the issue does appear for you in the fiddle?

Comment: I'm currently unable to reproduce this, same version of chrome/windows 7

Comment: @WesleyMurch good point! only 3 Plugins, trying to disable them and will let you know if it helped

Comment: @WesleyMurch disabled all Plugins/Addons still the same problem

Comment: To be clear, the issue *does* appear for you in the fiddle?

Comment: @WesleyMurch yes in stacksnippet, in jsfiddle and if I paste the given code on a blank .html file and open it

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with the code snipped in Chrome  59.0.3071.115 on macOS 10.12.5.

Comment: It only appears for me if `overflow-y: scroll` is set if I remove this then the box is not appearing. Maybe a rendering bug related to scrolling.

Comment: @t.niese Yes, it also doesn't appear if you change the width of the green `.resize-bar` but I need the `overflow-y: scroll;` and I need the `.resize-bar` to be that size

Comment: If I set `Show scroll bars` to `Always` in the system settings of macOS then the box doesn't appear, so I'm pretty sure it is a rendering bug related to the scrollbars.

Comment: @t.niese ok, thank you! I didn't find out that one. Where in the macOS settings can you enable / disable the `Show scroll bars Always`?

Comment: "System Preferences" > "General"

Comment: @t.niese yep! that does the trick! thank you

Comment: Well it does not really solve the problem ;)

Comment: @t.niese no it doesn't but now for me at least it's clear that it is a browser bug

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=743380#c2